# unzip a .zip file in hadoop using java

Tags: java, hadoop, unzip

I have a `.zip` file into the hadoop cluster named 'test.zip'. I am trying to unzip it into the hadoop cluster and store it under the name `test.txt` but, file is not getting unzipped and my below code is not giving me any error.

Code is able to unzip the file but not able to save the unzipped file into the cluster.

Comment: Try using a debugger? Worth pointing out zip files are not a native hadoop format

Comment: Yes. This is what I want. I want to unzip a `.zip` which is inside a Hadoop cluster using Java

Comment: I understood the question.... Please answer mine

Comment: @cricket_007 I am first creating the jar and then running using `hadoop jar` command and logging things to console. The code does unzips the file but doesn't saves it to the hadoop cluster

Answer (score 1):

> The code does unzips the file but doesn't saves it to the hadoop cluster

You're building a local FileOutputStream, and never writing anything back to HDFS

```
 File newFile = new File(outputFolder + "/" + fileName);
 new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
```

These need to replaced with a mkdirs call to the `FileSystem fs` object.

Or try to use `fs.createFile()` method, which returns an OutputStream builder that you can write to